# Cumulative sum and percentage on column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

`df`:

```
 fruit    val1 val2
0 orange    15    3
1 apple     10   13
2 mango     5    5
```

How do I get Pandas to give me a cumulative sum and percentage column on only `val1`?

Desired output:

`df_with_cumsum`:

```
 fruit    val1 val2   cum_sum    cum_perc
0 orange    15    3    15          50.00
1 apple     10   13    25          83.33
2 mango     5    5     30          100.00
```

I tried `df.cumsum()`, but it's giving me this error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
df['cum_sum'] = df['val1'].cumsum()
df['cum_perc'] = 100*df['cum_sum']/df['val1'].sum()
```

This will add the columns to `df`.  If you want a copy, copy `df` first and then do these operations on the copy.

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'instancemethod'` for the second line

Comment: Did you type `cumsum` or `cum_sum`?

Comment: something that may be useful too : pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format

Answer (score 7):

It's a good answer, but written in 2014.
I just modified a little bit, so it can pass the compiler and results looks similar to the example.

```
df['cum_sum'] = df["val1"].cumsum()
df['cum_perc'] = round(100*df.cum_sum/df["val1"].sum(),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good, but out of date. I have updated it so that it works.

df['cum_sum'] = df['val1'].cumsum()

df['cum_perc'] = round((df.cum_sum/df['val1'].sum())*100,2)

Comment: do format your answer as code